# How can I save MS Graph Message as .eml file

Tags: c#, arrays, email, graph, byte

I have a task to get e-mail from Exchange Server and save it as file attachement to CRM. I'm using Microsoft Graph SDK and C# to connect to Exchange Server.

I can get a mail as Microsoft.Graph.Message and I need to convert Microsoft.Graph.Message type to byte array to be able to save it to CRM.

I really don't know how. I've tried serialization by BinaryFormatter but the type Microsoft.Graph.Message is not marked as serializable.

I really don't have clue what to do now. Please can someone advice me? 
Thank you.

Comment: May be the question should be: How to get MIME content from Microsoft Graph SDK. I need to call this request: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{Id}/$value" by SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the syntax:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);
await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Content.GetAsync();
```

(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-4-get-mime-content)